# How to point directory to load index with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to configure `.htaccess` for my web site.

there are two folders in my web site  1 - `app` , 2  - `public`.

i want to load `index.php`  from public folder and restrict all direct access to app folder

the `.htaccess` i am using returns result `403 Forbidden`, but if i move `index.php` in root directory it is working, i just want to point that `index.php` is in `public` directory and send all requests there.

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /public/

    # Force to exclude the trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=307,L]

    # Restrict php files direct access
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.php[?\ ]
    RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]

    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you post your directory structure?

Comment: in app folder i have core side and in public side i have index and resources,   i have managed to avoid it like this.
in root i made  Rewrite rule to public directory and in public directory i pasted this htaccess and removed rewrite base, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i solved this problem like this,
for `root` directory i managed `.htaccess` like the code given down, the idea is to redirect all calls to `public` dir.

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^$   public/   [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And for filtering requests i used to put second `.htaccess` to `public` dir

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Force to exclude the trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=307,L]

    # Restrict php files direct access
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.php[?\ ]
    RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]

    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```